# Jquery Ajax Call to send data to the method when the a href clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0, umbraco7

I am trying to send the language type clicked from my master page into the `surfacecontroller` in the `App_code` folder. My HTML is like this below:

```
<div class="navbar-topbar clearfix">
    <div class="h5 pull-right"> 
        <span class="linkCA">
            <strong>CA</strong> 
            <a class="lang=en-CA" href="@NewUrlLink">EN</a> | 
            <a class="lang=fr-CA" href="@NewUrlLink">FR</a>
        </span> 
        <span class="linkUS">
            <strong>US</strong> 
            <a class="lang=en-US" href="@NewUrlLink">EN</a>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I am thinking is getting the class name and send it via AJAX call when the `a` is clicked. I have this method which I want to pass the type of language clicked to:

```
public string GetDictionaryItemByCulture(string key, string language)
{
    var currentLang = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
    var otherLang = myCulture(language);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(otherLang);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(otherLang);

    // String noLastSegment = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    string x = new UmbracoHelper().GetDictionaryValue(key);

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(currentLang);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(currentLang);

    return x;
}
```

I saw this AJAX method online which looks like what I need but I don't know how to wire it to work with my need .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
    $("#Result").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
            data: { someParameter: "some value" },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $("#Result").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it would be better practice to place the locale value in a `data-*` attribute in your HTML, with each `a` given a common class which the event handler can be attached to:

```
<div class="navbar-topbar clearfix">
    <div class="h5 pull-right"> 
        <span class="linkCA">
            <strong>CA</strong> 
            <a data-lang="en-CA" class="lang-trigger" href="@NewUrlLink">EN</a> | 
            <a data-lang="fr-CA" class="lang-trigger" href="@NewUrlLink">FR</a>
        </span> 
        <span class="linkUS">
            <strong>US</strong> 
            <a data-lang="en-US" class="lang-trigger" href="@NewUrlLink">EN</a>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

From there you can hook to the click of the `a`, read the `data-lang` attribute and send the information:

```
$('.lang-trigger').click(function() {
    var $a = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetDictionaryItemByCulture/",
        data: { 
            key: 'whatever this value should be...',
            lang: $a.data('lang')
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
});
```